# How to add badge to cart in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing e-commerce shopping app with ionic,angular i am a beginner my cart is working fine but i want to add a badge which shows quantity am not able to do it.

Here is my cart controller

```
.controller('cartCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,sharedCartService,$ionicPopup,$state,$http) {
     $scope.cart=sharedCartService.cart_item;  // Loads users cart

    $scope.get_qty = function() {
      $scope.total_qty=0;
      $scope.total_amount=0;
    }
    //onload event-- to set the values
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
        $scope.cart=sharedCartService.cart;
        $scope.total_qty=sharedCartService.total_qty;
        $scope.total_amount=sharedCartService.total_amount;     
    });



        //remove function
    $scope.removeFromCart=function(c_id){
        $scope.cart.drop(c_id); 
        $scope.total_qty=sharedCartService.total_qty;
        $scope.total_amount=sharedCartService.total_amount;

    };

    $scope.inc=function(c_id){
        $scope.cart.increment(c_id);
        $scope.total_qty=sharedCartService.total_qty;
        $scope.total_amount=sharedCartService.total_amount;
    };

    $scope.dec=function(c_id){
        $scope.cart.decrement(c_id);
        $scope.total_qty=sharedCartService.total_qty;
        $scope.total_amount=sharedCartService.total_amount;
    };


$scope.checkout=function(){
        if($scope.total_amount>0){
            $state.go('checkOut');
        }
        else{
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'No item in your Cart',
                template: 'Please add Some Items!'
            });
        }
    };
```

Menu from where user adds product to cart

```
   <ion-list ng-repeat="item in menu_items">

        <ion-item class="item-thumbnail-left" >
            <img  ng-src="{{'img/'+ item.p_image_id +'.jpg'}}"  ng-click="showProductInfo(item.p_id,item.p_description,item.p_image_id,item.p_name,item.p_price)" >

            <p style="position:absolute;right:10px;">
            <a  ng-click="addToCart(item.p_id,item.p_image_id,item.p_name,item.p_price)" class="button  button-balanced button-clear   icon ion-android-cart">  </a> 
            </p>

            <h2  ng-click="showProductInfo(item.p_id,item.p_description,item.p_image_id,item.p_name,item.p_price)" > {{item.p_name}} </h2>
            <p   ng-click="showProductInfo(item.p_id,item.p_description,item.p_image_id,item.p_name,item.p_price)">Price: &#8377; {{item.p_price}}</p>
        </ion-item>


    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Where do you want the "quantity badge" to be displayed? Is it going to be just a number or an image that you get from somewhere?

Comment: I need just a number beside my cart icon.From menu when customer adds a item to cart i want to show number